# Django: How do I download .xls file through a django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a button which downloads a excel file with extension `.xls`. I am using module `xlrd` to parse the file and return it back to the user. However it appears to add the object name into the excel file instead of the data.

How can I return the file to the user with the data rather than the objects name?

**View**

```py
def download_file(self, testname):
    import csv, socket, os, xlrd
    extension = '.xls'
    path = r"C:\tests\{}_Report{}".format(testname, extension)   
    try:
        f = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
        response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}_Report{}'.format(testname, extension)
        return response
    except Exception as Error:
        return HttpResponse(Error)
    return redirect('emissions_dashboard:overview_view_record')
```

**Excel result**

Download successful:

[image]

Content:

[image]

*Note: I understand this is an old file format but is required for this particular project.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to send a xlrd.book.Book object, not a file.

You used xlrd to do your things in the workbook, and then saved to a file.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
#... do something
workbook.save(path)
```

Now you send it like any other file:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
  response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="application/ms-excel")
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}_Report{}'.format(testname, extension)
```